# Unknown server-side error occurred for Unknown device or simulator when UUID exists

Tags: automation, ios-simulator, appium-ios

I have migrated settings of my iMac to another iMac and when I tried to run iOS test on current iMac, error occurs which says 
'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unknown device or simulator UDID: 'A379B193-5472-4D39-BF00-AFEAB29858E7'

However Simulator with above UUID exists

I tried reading appium logs but have not found anything conclusive. Please see logs below:

```
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session

[HTTP] {"desiredCapabilities":{"deviceName":"iPhone 8 Plus","platformName":"iOS","automationName":"XCUITest","browserName":"Safari","udid":"A379B193-5472-4D39-BF00-AFEAB29858E7","autoDismissAlerts":true,"simpleIsVisibleCheck":true},"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"platformName":"iOS","browserName":"Safari"}]}}

[debug] [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"deviceName":"iPhone 8 Plus","platformName":"iOS","automationName":"XCUITest","browserName":"Safari","udid":"A379B193-5472-4D39-BF00-AFEAB29858E7","autoDismissAlerts":true,"simpleIsVisibleCheck":true},null,{"firstMatch":[{"platformName":"iOS","browserName":"Safari"}]}]

[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1562150024125 (14:33:44 GMT+0400 (Gulf Standard Time))

[Appium] Could not parse W3C capabilities: 'deviceName' can't be blank

[Appium] Trying to fix W3C capabilities by merging them with JSONWP caps

[BaseDriver] The capabilities ["deviceName","automationName","udid","autoDismissAlerts","simpleIsVisibleCheck"] are not standard capabilities and should have an extension prefix

[Appium] Creating new XCUITestDriver (v2.94.2) session

[Appium] Capabilities:

[Appium]   deviceName: iPhone 8 Plus

[Appium]   automationName: XCUITest

[Appium]   udid: A379B193-5472-4D39-BF00-AFEAB29858E7

[Appium]   autoDismissAlerts: true

[Appium]   simpleIsVisibleCheck: true

[Appium]   platformName: iOS

[Appium]   browserName: Safari

[debug] [BaseDriver] W3C capabilities {"alwaysMatch":{"appium:dev... and MJSONWP desired capabilities {"deviceName":"iPhone 8 Plu... were provided

[debug] [BaseDriver] Creating session with W3C capabilities: {"alwaysMatch":{"appium:dev...

[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 50086b20-bb82-4899-818b-b169422707c3

[debug] [XCUITest] Current user: 'ayushgoel'

[debug] [XCUITest] Xcode version set to '10.2.1' (tools v10.2.1.0.1.1554506761)

[debug] [XCUITest] iOS SDK Version set to '12.2'

[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'xcodeDetailsRetrieved' logged at 1562150024191 (14:33:44 GMT+0400 (Gulf Standard Time))

[debug] [XCUITest] Available devices: 

[XCUITest] Error: Unknown device or simulator UDID: 'A379B193-5472-4D39-BF00-AFEAB29858E7'

[XCUITest]     at XCUITestDriver.determineDevice$ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:693:17)

[XCUITest]     at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)

[XCUITest]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)

[XCUITest]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.<computed> [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)

[XCUITest]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)

[debug] [XCUITest] Not clearing log files. Use `clearSystemFiles` capability to turn on.

[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1562150024370 (14:33:44 GMT+0400 (Gulf Standard Time))

[debug] [W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Unknown device or simulator UDID: 'A379B193-5472-4D39-BF00-AFEAB29858E7'

[debug] [W3C]     at XCUITestDriver.determineDevice$ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:693:17)

[debug] [W3C]     at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)

[debug] [W3C]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)

[debug] [W3C]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.<computed> [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)

[debug] [W3C]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)

[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 246 ms - 1197
```

Test is running of previous iMac and there is no difference. Please help me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can someone please reply?

Comment: This error does not appear when Appium and Xcode is updated.